# How can I allocate a certain amount of points within a polygon dependent on the polygon size? (5-10ha polygon gets 5, 10-25ha polygon gets 10 etc)

Tags: qgis

I'm wishing to allocate a certain amount of random points within a polygon but on the basis of polygon size. For example and context agricultural fields and sampling points.

a field of less than 0.5ha would be allocated 3 random points
a field between 0.5 - 1.5ha would be allocated 5 random points
a field between 1.5 - 2.5ha would be allocated 10 random points

Is there a way to implement this within QGIS without a large amount of coding.

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Define your categories.

Step 2: Put then in a `CASE WHEN` expression, e.g.

```sql
CASE
  WHEN $area < 5000 THEN 3
  WHEN ($area >= 5000 AND $area < 15000) THEN 5
  ...
END
```

This is just a machine-readable version of your categories from step 1.

Step 3: Feed the complete expression to the data defined override of the field controlling the number of points per feature of the `random points in polygons`-tool. Execute and save the output.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=data%20defined%20override#data-defined-override-setup

Comment: Thanks very much Erik. I first put the '...' within the code which is why it wasn't working

Comment: I have noticed for the most part it works, but for some reason some fields which should be 15 are 10 and some that should be 10 are 5... do you know why this might be?

Comment: How do you determine whether the output is wrong or not? Can you provide example data?

Comment: So the fields fall within 4 increments as explained in the question. But for some reason some fields don't have the correct about of random samples within... Such as a field which is 2.9ha, which should have 15 cores allocated, however there's only 10. (I have created a WHEN/THEN for fields sized 2.5ha to 15ha which outputs 15 points - just to let you know)

Comment: Please provide the full expression you used.

Comment: CASE
  WHEN $area/10000 < 0.5 THEN 3
  WHEN ($area/10000 >= 0.5 AND $area/10000 < 1.5) THEN 5
  WHEN ($area/10000 >= 1.5 AND $area/10000 < 2.5) THEN 10
  WHEN ($area/10000 >= 2.5 AND $area/10000 < 15) THEN 15
END